# WP REST APIの出力について

Tags: json, wordpress, api, rest

現在WordPress4.7.5にてサイトを制作、運用しております。
サイト軽量化のために、WP REST APIv2を使用し、記事情報などを出力させるために更新中なのですが、以下の点の部分について、Googleなどで調べているのですが当該の記事に当たらず苦戦を強いられております。

・カスタム投稿タイプのカテゴリー出力
・Advanced Custom Field Proの作成項目json整形およびhtml表示

この2点において、皆様からご教授いただけますと幸いです。
ACF to REST APIは実装しており、`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/example(acf)`にて出力は確認しております。
カスタム投稿タイプのカテゴリに関しましては、IDは出力が出来ているのを確認しているのですが、登録名での出力が確認を取れていないのと、整形が出来ておりません。

呼出、整形、出力を行っている記述は下記になります。

```
$(function(){
  $html_set = '';
  $.getJSON("http://aquariumbynaked.com/wp-json/wp/v2/latest-contents/?_embed", function(data){

    $html_set = '<style>' +
      'ul.wp_api-unit{display:block;}'+
      'ul.wp_api-unit li{clear:both; margin-bottom:15px; padding-bottom: 15px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;}'+
      'ul.wp_api-unit a{width:100%;display:block;}'+
      'ul.wp_api-unit .thumbnail{display:inline-block;width:28%;margin:0;padding:0 2% 0 0; vertical-align:top;}'+
      'ul.wp_api-unit .contents {display:inline-block;width:70%;}'+
      'ul.wp_api-unit .contents h1{font-size:1.6em; margin:0; paddin-bottom: 15px; margin:0; padding:0;}'+
      'ul.wp_api-unit .contents p{text-align: right; width:100%;}' +
      '</style>';

    $html_set += '<div>';

   $(data).each(function(){

    $title = this.single_title;
    $excerpt = this.excerpt;
    $date = new Date(this.date_gmt);
    $month = $date.getMonth()+1;
    $date_set = $date.getFullYear() + '.' + $month + '.' + $date.getDate() + '.';
    $thumbnail_src = this._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url;

    $html_set += '<div class="contents-inner box-area pos-r">' + '<div class="contents-image thumbnail-55 thumbnailImg pos-r" style="background-image: url('+ $thumbnail_src +')"></div>' + '<a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank" class="contents-links web-links pos-a-area"></a>' + '<div class="contents-text pos-a">' + '<h3>' + $title +'</h3>' + '<div class"event-date">' + $date + '</div>' + '</div>' +

    '</div>'+
    '';
    })
    $html_set += '</div>';
    $($html_set).appendTo('.LatestContents');
  })
});
```

知識不足で申し訳ございません、皆様何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: カスタム投稿タイプのカテゴリー（タクソノミー）の全データは　 http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/latest-contents_cat でjsonが得られます。
IDを指定した個別データは http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/latest-contents_cat/9　となります。
実際に処理する場合は、タクソノミー全データを配列に入れ直し参照する処理が良いと思います。（URLはexample.comから直して確認して下さい。）

Comment: お返事遅くなりまして。申し訳ありません。
ご教授ありがとうございます。
教えていただいた通り、全データの取得は完了いたしました。
参照が現状出来ていないのですが、何かサンプルコードなどございますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

スクリプトを正しく表示する為に、回答欄に書きました。
jqueryを使用し、タクソノミを「test_taxonomy」と作成したときの投稿記事中（posts）に指定されたターム名を取り出す、例です。

```
$(function(){
    var taxonomys = new Object;
    $.getJSON('http://hoge.jp/wp-json/wp/v2/test_taxonomy', function(json){
        //test_taxonomyのタームID、ターム名から変換テーブル作成
        for(var i=0;i < json.length;i++){
            taxonomys[json[i].id] = json[i].name;
        }

        //記事データ中のtest_taxonomyタームIDからターム名に変換
        $.getJSON('http://hoge.jp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', function(json1){
            for(var i=0;i < json1.length;i++){
                for(var j=0;j < json1[i].test_taxonomy.length;j++){
                    var term_name = taxonomys[json1[i].test_taxonomy[j]];
                    console.log(term_name);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: 丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございます。
`console.log(term_name)`のところで、記事出力用のコード（質問投稿に記載）を設置し出力させようとしたところ、カテゴリ情報が記事と紐付かず、出力されてしまいました。

上記（質問投稿記載コード）で出力をさせる場合はどう記載するのがよろしいのでしょうか...？


初心者な故、些末な質問までしてしまい申し訳ありません。
引き続きご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。